finding status of contacts in group
Version: 5.72.3
Folks sign up for my newsletter through a profile form and are added to group "Mailings". Some of these go right into Mailings but others (over 100) have been assigned a status "Pending (by Email)". These people are not getting my newsletter nor do they appear in the group "Mailings" and I cannot search for "Pending" as described in the User Guide under "Groups and Tags".
I started removing the Pending status one-by-one using a report but there must be a better way to do this.

SearchKit does allow you to search for Contacts in Groups, with Group Status, but my testing doesn't then let one update them in bulk. hmm.

it does. i just needed to start from the right entity

SearchKit can offer you a bulk option

find all contacts with Pending
add them to Group

Example SK is here but will flush in a few hours https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/edit/49


